# Retrieve data from Firebase to create address to edit in the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, this is how my Firebase database looks like:

[image]

I am currently trying to read the value of **UserInformation/Shift/zTZ0U1K8aGb6bP94YTUA50ZwIlx2/Shift** in order to set the value of **ShiftInformation/1514855312873/Team/zTZ0U1K8aGb6bP94YTUA50ZwIlx2** to null.

When I press a button "buttonMyShift", I need to read the value "1514855312873" because it was generated from System.getCurrentTimeMillis().
I have been trying to accomplish that by changing the value inside a "onDataChange" method, ut the app either crashes or deletes only UserInformation/Shift.

Here is my activity code:

```
        if (view == buttonMyShift){
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference("UserInformation/Shift/").child(user.getUid()).child("Shift");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Read the value of UserInformation/Shift/user.getUid()/Shift
                    SHIFT uShift = dataSnapshot.getValue(SHIFT.class);

                    //Setting the value of userShift to UserInformation/Shift/user.getUid()/Shift
                    String userShift = uShift.toString().trim();

                    //Setting the value of ShiftInformation/userShift/Team/user.getUid() to null
                    mReference = database.getReference("ShiftInformation").child(userShift).child("Team").child(user.getUid());
                    mReference.setValue(null);


                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });

        //set UserInformation/Shift/user.getUid to null
        SHIFT nshift = new SHIFT(null);
        databaseReference.setValue(nshift);

        Toast.makeText(MainMenuActivity.this,"Adeus!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //leave the activity

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this,BadgeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Thanks For The Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of your `Shift` field, which is `1514855312873`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference shiftRef = rootRef.child("UserInformation").child("Shift").child(user.getUid()).child("Shift");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String shift = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", shift);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
shiftRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
1514855312873
```

Your `DatabaseReference` was correct but the problem in your code is that you are using `getChildren()` method when there is no need.